# awk - different error in different pc

Tags: bash, awk, runtime-error, gawk

I've written a small program in **bash/gawk** which I intend to run locally on **mobaxterm**. My problem is that while it works perfectly in one PC, it consistently gives me an error 127 when I try it in the other PC.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

# Note: strings' 1st character is at column 1.

# Before first line.
BEGIN {
   print "" >> JOB_OUT
   print "GAwk Started" >> JOB_OUT

   # Variables Init.
   line_crnt= ""
   line_writ= ""
   #
   load_indx= ""
   srch_indx= ""
   #
   line_cnt_fltr= 0
   line_cnt_base= 0
   line_cnt_comn= 0
   line_cnt_diff= 0

   # We will use array:
   # tbl_filter
}

# For each line of input.

# 1st File (filter).
# Load filter to table.
FNR==NR {
   line_cnt_fltr+= 1
   line_crnt= $0

   load_indx= substr(line_crnt, p_fltr_srt, p_fltr_len)
   # load_indx=line_crnt
   tbl_filter[load_indx]+=1

   next
  }

 # 2nd File (base).
 # Read base, check filter, write output.
{ 
   line_cnt_base+= 1
   line_crnt= $0

   srch_indx= substr(line_crnt, p_base_srt, p_base_len)
   line_writ= line_crnt

   if (srch_indx in tbl_filter)
   {
      print line_writ >> FILE_OT_COMN
      line_cnt_comn+= 1
   }
   else
   {
      print line_writ >> FILE_OT_DIFF
      line_cnt_diff+= 1
   }
}

# After last line.
END {
   print "" >> JOB_OUT
   print "Read : line_cnt_fltr = @" line_cnt_fltr "@" >> JOB_OUT
   print "Read : line_cnt_base = @" line_cnt_base "@" >> JOB_OUT
   print "Same : line_cnt_comn = @" line_cnt_comn "@" >> JOB_OUT
   print "Diff : line_cnt_diff = @" line_cnt_diff "@" >> JOB_OUT
   print "" >> JOB_OUT
   print "GAwk Ended" >> JOB_OUT
}
```

I actually get no error message, but the exit status is 127, and that happens exactly when my bash script calls the gawk script.

In both pcs gawk is at /bin/gawk.

This being the code that calls it:

```
$JOB_RUN -b  -v FILE_OT_COMN=$FILE_OT_COMN \
         -v FILE_OT_DIFF=$FILE_OT_DIFF \
         -v JOB_OUT=$JOB_OUT           \
         -v p_fltr_srt=$fltr_srt       \
         -v p_fltr_len=$fltr_len       \
         -v p_base_srt=$base_srt       \
         -v p_base_len=$base_len       \
         $FILE_IN_FLTR  $FILE_IN_BASE  \
         2>$JOB_ERR
```

and if you see by execution all variables are there:

```
./RN_Files_Cmpr.gawk -b -v FILE_OT_COMN=V_20170309.TXT.xstY -v FILE_OT_DIFF=V_20170309.TXT.xstN -v JOB_OUT=RUN.RN_Files_Cmpr.gawk.bsh.outlist -v p_fltr_srt=1 -v p_fltr_len=2 -v p_base_srt=117 -v p_base_len=2 timo.txt V_20170309.TXT
```

I read that error 127 comes up when it fails to find some executable, which i believe this case has to be gawk, even though its there. By the way gawk runs perfectly :

```
gawk '{ print substr($0,1,2) }' TESTFILE.txt
```

gives proper output.

Can someone point me at what i m doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: What is `./RN_Files_Cmpr.gawk`?

Comment: The script i posted in the beginning, now when i jumble up the interpreter, it gives me no error, it just outputs "bad interpreter", but when i add the correct path, it hangs and returns error code 127.

Comment: If `gawk` is `/bin/gawk` why do you have `/usr/bin/gawk` in your shebang line?

Comment: as alternative shebang `#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f`